# Using a join in Hibernate HQL update query

Tags: nhibernate, join, hql

```
string query = "update User u set u.PointsTotal = 1 join u.Rounds r where r.RoundId = :round and (r.Row1 & :val) > 0";

NHibernateSession.CreateQuery(query)
    .SetByte("val", (byte)val)
    .SetInt32("round", roundId)
    .ExecuteUpdate();
```

Just gives me "The given key was not present in the dictionary."

And yes, the relations works as expected, can do selects....

Answer (score 5):

Ok solved this one, seems like you have to do a subquery...

```
string query = "update User u set u.PointsTotal = 1 where u.Id in (select u2.Id from User u2 join u2.Rounds r where r.RoundId = :round and (r.Row1 & :val) > 0)";

NHibernateSession.CreateQuery(query)
    .SetByte("val", (byte)val)
    .SetInt32("round", roundId)
    .ExecuteUpdate();
```